# Unable to view django error pages on Google Cloud web app

Tags: python, django, google-compute-engine

Settings.py DEBUG=True
But the django web application shows Server Error 500.
I need to see the error pages to debug what is wrong on the production server. 
The web application works fine in development server offline.

The google logs does not show detail errors. Only shows the http code of the request.

Answer (score 0):

For Getting error in google logs. You have to add `Logging` functionality in Django.

Django uses Python’s builtin logging module to perform system logging. A logger is the entry point into the logging system. You have to define an `Error` logger for getting error logs.

For Example:

```py
# import the logging library
import logging

# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_view(request, arg1, arg):
    ...
    if bad:
        # Log an error message
        logger.error('Something went wrong!')
```

Please refer to official Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, its probably not the error from the django side but the GCP itself. Its an error from google servers.There must be somethings probably which aint accepted by the server from the code.Try [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff?hl=en/). This can come in handy.

Comment: The exponential backoff is not applicable in this case. Thanks for your response anyway. Also this python related not java.

Answer (score 0):

GCP uses Stackdriver as the main tool for logging and by default does not collect data from Python nor frameworks like Django.

For collecting Python logs you must enable it following these steps [1].

Additionally, there are not official steps for adding Django logs to Stackdriver, but I recommend you take a look at this post [2] about how to seup Stackdriver logging for Django App using Gunicorn

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python

[2] https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2018/09/google-stackdriver-logging-for-django-app/

Comment: Thank you I am currently following the agiliq post.The Stackdriver Error reporting tab shows does error reporting but it doesn't log out everything like the django error pages. I will give feedback later.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for replying to my question. The project had prod.py (production settings file, DEBUG=False) and a dev.py (development settings file). When python manage.py is called it directly calls dev.py(DEBUG=True). However, when I push to google app engine main.py is used to specify how to run the application. main.py calls wsgi.py which calls prod.pd (DEBUG=False). This is why the django error pages were not showing. I really appreciate you all. VictorTorres, Mahirq9 and ParthS007